# Is there anyway to see all board across multiple email accounts in Trello?

Tags: trello

I have been invited to multiple private Trello boards through different email accounts.

So my friend invited me into a board using one email address (my home address) and another person invited me into a board using my school email address.

Is there a way to see all of my boards at once (instead of having to keep logging in an out of Trello to see the different boards)?

Answer (score 5):

Trello does not support this capability.  However, if you have appropriate permissions, you can give yourself permission to both boards with one email address.  Here is the Trello help topic for merging accounts:

[Merging multiple Trello accounts](http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/984283-merging-multiple-trello-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

The above idea to permission the email accounts is the best way. There is also a quick way to fake it - use two different browsers. When you log into an account on, say, Chrome any tabs in Chrome will relate to that first_account@blah.net but if you open IE or Safari etc then you can log onto different_account@somefinkelse.org

Comment: "Above" what? Answers can be sorted several different ways.